Set data in a cross-domain localStorage by iframe
I want to set cross-domain localStorage data, I created an embedded page to receive and set localStorage data b.com/receive.html which listen window's message event, and set the received data into localStorage. The host page is a.com/host.html which has an IFrame element to connect and post data to embedded page.
The embedded page could receive data and set localStorage when it is in IFrame. But if I access the embedded page directly, the localStorage is not which is in IFrame although the tow pages has same origin.
Is localStorage separated is IFrame?

This used to be possible, but it got abused by people using it as a workaround when it became common to block third party cookies. So now we no longer get to have nice things.
Over the years people have come up with workarounds, but you're fighting a loosing battle with the browsers if you go down this route.
So to answer your question, yes it is now separated in the iframe, which is actually progress. At one point if a script received a message event, you were then blocked from using localstorage.
